# Issues with mysql search results being incorrect

Tags: mysql

I have some serious issues with the results returned from an SQL query on my website.
I have a specific product with a model number of DC250, and yet if you search fro DC250, the actual product is not displayed first in the results, but way down in 26th place. Given that this model number is an exact match to the search results, why should it be so far down?

Below is the sql query that is run.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.products_model,  p.products_id, pd.products_name,
 IF( pd.products_name LIKE "dc250", 40, IF( pd.products_name LIKE "dc250%", 20, 0 )
 + IF( MATCH(pd.products_name, pd.products_description) AGAINST("dc250 dc250s"),
 MATCH(pd.products_name, pd.products_description) AGAINST("dc250 dc250s") * 40, 0) )
 + IF( MATCH(m.manufacturers_name) AGAINST("dc250 dc250s"), MATCH(m.manufacturers_name) AGAINST("dc250 dc250s") * 0, 0 )
 + IF( MATCH(p.products_model) AGAINST("dc250 dc250s"), MATCH(p.products_model) AGAINST("dc250 dc250s") * 20, 0)
 + IF( MATCH(mtpd.metatags_keywords, mtpd.metatags_description) AGAINST("dc250 dc250s"),
 MATCH(mtpd.metatags_keywords, mtpd.metatags_description) AGAINST("dc250 dc250s")* 30, 0)
 + (pd.products_viewed / 3475.6985) as weight FROM (products p LEFT JOIN manufacturers m
 USING(manufacturers_id), products_description pd, categories c, products_to_categories p2c )         
 LEFT JOIN meta_tags_products_description mtpd ON mtpd.products_id= p2c.products_id              
 AND mtpd.language_id = 1 WHERE (p.products_status = 1 AND p.products_id = pd.products_id                
 AND pd.language_id = 1 AND p.products_id = p2c.products_id                
 AND p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id  AND (
 MATCH(pd.products_name, pd.products_description) 
 AGAINST("dc250* dc250s*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 OR MATCH(p.products_model) AGAINST("dc250* dc250s*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)             
 OR MATCH(m.manufacturers_name) AGAINST("dc250* dc250s*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)             
 OR MATCH(mtpd.metatags_keywords, mtpd.metatags_description) 
 AGAINST("dc250* dc250s*" IN BOOLEAN MODE))) 
 order by p.products_model
```

Comment: You are ordering by the model, and that means it orders by the model name alphabetically.

Comment: But even if i remove the order by, the dc250 still doesn't return at the top of the list. Is there a way to order by match?

Comment: `MATCH` returns a relevance score that can be used to order the results by – but since you’re using `MATCH` in so many places, you would have to combine all those scores somehow beforehand. And a query that uses `MATCH` so much is likely going to be quite inefficient … you should seriously think about whether a different data model might not be a better option.